# How do you change the wrap property for the iCarousel library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, icarousel

I'm really confused. Do I have to go in the iCarousel.h file and change it there, or can I access the property in code and then reloadData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a delegate method you can call:

```
- (BOOL)carouselShouldWrap:(iCarousel *)carousel {
//wrap all carousels
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@iOSGuru248 is right. If it not works, try this

```
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value{
    if(option == iCarouselOptionWrap){
     return YES;
    }
    return value;
}
```